# How to make Ruby on Rails authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have this problem for my social network website. I want to make an authorization for members based on the member level, if the member's level is below then the others, he can't chat or seeing the profile picture. Is there any plug in that can handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declarative Authorization. Very powerful. Would definitely recommend it. There's even an awesome railscast on this by Ryan Bates.

Comment: Is this plugin can compare between two member with different level? For example, the higher member level is available for send message to member on same level or below level. But, the low level member can't send a message to higher level member

Comment: You can customize it to work the way you want. Play around with it and you'll get the drift.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following (both can be found on GitHub):

CanCan--pretty straightforward and well-documented. The author is Ryan Bates of Railscasts fame. One nice thing about it is you can identify all of your permissions within a single file.

RESTful_ACL--not as popular but easy to implement. Permissions are defined in each model you want to protect. I wrote a series on implementing RESTful_ACL in my Rails blog: http://everydayrails.com/2010/06/16/authorization-restful-acl-1.html

Comment: How can I compare between two member with different level? For example, the higher member level is available for send message to member on same level or below level. But, the low level member can't send a message to higher level member.

Answer (score 0):

Try Aegis - http://www.agileweboperations.com/role-based-permissions-for-your-ruby-on-rails-application